# What does it mean for a matrix to induce a norm?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given the following math problem:
Consider the scalar product   $\langle x,y\rangle = x^TAy$  given by the matrix:

$$
     A=  \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 2 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        2 & 0 & 8 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Determine the length of $(2, 1, 0)^T$ with respect to the norm induced by the scalar product.

What does it mean for a norm to be induced by something? In the answers they say that the norm is induced by the matrix $A$. Does it mean that this vector is not in a normal coordinate system but somehow inside this matrix?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: A scalar product defined in the problem: $(x,y)= x^T A y $. A scalar product induces a norm by the equation  $\|x\|= \sqrt {(x,x)}. $ Thus, the norm induced by a matrix simply means the norm which is created by this specific inner product

Comment: @Matt, looks like an answer, methinks.

Comment: @J.M. indeed, I still do not understand the stackexchange etiquette for "softish" questions (eg definitions, terminology, references). It always seems comments are more appropriate to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix $A$ which is symmetric and positive definite defines (as your posts states) an inner product:
$$
\langle x, y\rangle \stackrel{\rm def}{=} x^T A y, \tag{$\forall x,y$}
$$

Now, an inner product defines (induces) a norm by setting $\lVert x\rVert \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \sqrt{\langle x, x\rangle}$.

So "a symmetric positive definite matrix $A$ induces a norm."

Comment: ...and of course, the conventional inner product is a special case, since the identity matrix is SPD.

Comment: Indeed. (Also, this is for the case of real matrices and inner products, but generalizes to complex ones.)

Comment: I think i was having issues with what "defines" meant. But I think I understood that multiplying vectors by a symmetric and positive definite matrix will yield an inner product. So basically $A$ just defines a specific scalar product. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. (Also, a way to remember the dependence on $A$ is to write the norm as, e.g., $\lVert x\rVert_A$ whenever there may be an ambiguity.)